# AttributeError: module 'utils' has no attribute 'init logging'

Tags: python, error-handling, anaconda, detection, attributeerror

input code:

```
import os
import logging
import logging.handlers
import random

import numpy as np
import skvideo.io
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import utils
```

Some codes here ... ... ... then:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
log = utils.init_logging()

if not os.path.exists(IMAGE_DIR):
    log.debug("Creating image directory `%s`...", IMAGE_DIR)
    os.makedirs(IMAGE_DIR)

main()
```

Output:

```
AttributeError: module 'utils' has no attribute 'init_logging'
```

I have tried to rename the file into utils.py. Nothing

Comment: Renaming your file to `utils.py` is a bad idea because it will then shadow the actual module.

Comment: Thx for reply. I was advised to do that. Any other suggestions?@roganjosh

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're making a tutorial of Making Road Traffic Counting App based on Computer Vision and OpenCV. You just need to download from github the file named "utils.py" that the author made.